# Out of Stock issue

Tags: magento-1.9, out-of-stock

All my configurable products showing out of stock in magento CE 1.9 front end. Please advice on this how to fix the issue.

All the simple product having qty and status is active.

Comment: Did you tried reindexing?

Comment: take a screen of your product inventory page -- also, what code are you using to dipslay the current stock in the front end?

Comment: This is the code am using for current stock.            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
      <?php else: ?>
       <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?><?php echo $_product->isSaleable();?></span></p>
      <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score -3):

Check if the product is "availability: in stock", in the inventory tab from product edit

Comment: Yes, it is in stock.